# How to integrate Amazon Alexa with Salesforce Einstein Bot

Tags: salesforce, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, salesforce-einstein

I have requirement where I have existing Salesforce Bot for lead creation & loan processing. Now I need to integrate same with Alexa. So agent can use Alexa device to create leads using Salesforce Einstein Bot. Alexa should be just medium to interact with Salesforce Einstein Bot. NLP will happen on existing Einstein Bot. I read somewhere that we can integrate Alexa with Einstein Bot but I was not able to find implementation link anywhere.

Can someone guide here.

Thanks,

Ani

Comment: You might try to Salesforce Trailhead materials on Alexa as a starting point: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/innovate-with-alexa-and-amazon-web-services  You'll get better help here once you have some code started.

Comment: Alexa doesn't pass through customer audio to 3rd parties. Alexa will process the audio and pass specific values from it in an intent request.